# Bottom Border of Table Row isn't showing in IE

Tags: asp.net, html

http://www.surefiretaxes.com/Business/Crosslink-Tax-Software

Under the video and 2 images where it says "Features" this shows up correctly in Chrome/FireFox, but doesn't show up in IE9. What is really confusing me is when i take the same information out and throw it into DreamWeaver it works perfectly fine.

```
<style>
.Comparisonlbl                               {font-size: 13pt; color: #0061A0; line-    height:1.2em}
.Comparison                {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
.Comparison tr                             {border-bottom: 1px solid #4D4D4D; line-height:1.3em}
.Comparison th                             {font-size: 11pt; color: #595959; padding: 15px 0 3px; text-align:center; vertical-align:top}
.Comparison td                             {text-align:left; color:#4D4D4D; font-size: small;}
</style>
</head>

<body>



<table class="Comparison" width="700px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="padding: 15px 0px 3px; text-align: center; color: maroon; font-size: 11pt; vertical-align: top;" width="324">Features Not Mentioned in the Video Above</th>
      <th style="padding: 15px 0px 3px; text-align: center; color: maroon; font-size: 11pt; vertical-align: top;" width="364">Feature Description</th>
    </tr>
 <tr>
      <th>Free Included Features:<br></th>
  <th><div align="center"></div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td><strong>Free Unlimited E-Filing</strong><br>
<span style="font-size: x-small;">1040s, 1041, 1120s/c, 1065, 706, 709, 990, 5500 and more</span></td>
      <td>You can E-File any Individual or Business form for any of the 50 U.S. states free of charge. To see a complete list of all the forms that you can e-file for free see our [<a href="/Home/Tax-Forms" target="blank">Included Tax Forms</a>] page.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="line-height: 1.3em; border-bottom-width: 0px;">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Free Included Features:<br>
        <div style="font-size: 9pt;">Crosslink doesn't offer these options</div></th>
      <th><div align="center"></div></th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Automatic Backup Software</strong></td>
      <td>Backup your Tax Data from any year using our backup software. You can also retrieve these returns anywhere anytime. - [<a href="/Business/New-2013#Backup" target="blank">read more</a>]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>E-File 2010, 2011, and 2012 returns</strong></td>
      <td>With Sure-Fire you will be able to E-File 2010, 2011, and 2012 tax returns. This feature isn't available with many software vendors. - [<a href="/Business/New-2013#EFILE" target="blank">read more</a>]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Interview Form Sheet</strong></td>
      <td>Our software has a built in Interview Form Sheet that asks you questions to help determine what forms are needed for the return. - [<a href="/Business/New-2013#Interview" target="blank">read more</a>]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td vAlign="center;"><strong>Refund by Pre-Paid Mastercard</strong>
</td>
<td vAlign="center;" width="85"><img border="0" src="/SureFire/v2/moneywise_card.png" width="60"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
  <td>Give your customers a Pre-Paid Mastercard their refund will be deposited onto before they leave your store. - [<a href="WesternUnion-Moneywise" target="blank">read more</a>]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Sure-Fire Assistant</strong></td>
  <td>This software shows videos on how to do everything from a 1040 return to an amended return. Also, this software can automatically fix any software issues you might run into 9 times out of 10 without contacting support. - [<a href="/Business/Sure-Fire-Assistant" target="blank">read more</a>]</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think border bottom works on a tr.  Try putting it on a td tag.

Comment: apparently this is the case. It's very weird how it was working in DreamWeaver/Copying the code above directly to notepad and opening it in IE, but on my page it didn't work. I just went and added it to all the TD's and now it works fine. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to declare a doctype such as:

DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

FYI you will need the proper markers around that, however I can't place them.
IE gets picky about table styling without them. Hope it works, sorry I would normally test it first for you but I'm on mobile.